# Find AD users who can reset the passwords of other AD users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm on a special mission defined by my boss. 
His question is 'How many users in our AD can reset the passwords of other users?'

I'm not an AD admin, I only have a normal AD user account and no special privileges. However I can retrieve attributes of other users like the 'samAccountType' or the 'userAccountControl' with Get-ADUser and all these other fancy powershell scripts.

My question is: Is there a way to retrieve information which I can use to answer his question?

Thank you for any hint!

Comment: Whether user A can reset the password of user B is determined by the security permissions (ACL) on user B.  So you'll need to enumerate all the user accounts, and for each one read the permissions, collecting a list of users and groups with the ability to reset at least one user's password.  You'll then need to enumerate the group memberships, including nested groups - although depending on the size of the AD, that part might be more easily done by hand.  (Depending on the way the AD is configured, you might not be able to get all the relevant data without admin privilege.)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Sysinternals tools (now part of Microsoft) in particular AccessChk and AccessEnum. Otherwise you would need to script something that retrieves all machines from AD and then iterate over them with an administrator account that has the rights to view all permissions of all filesystem objects. Another option is to get help from this [solution](http://www.lepide.com/lepideauditor/active-directory-auditing.html) which lets you which object have which permissions in AD.

Here is an earlier [thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/282047-how-to-get-list-of-all-effective-rights-permissions-on-active-directory-objects) might helps you to get list of all effective rights/permissions on Active Directory objects.

How do you discover what permissions an AD group has, if you have no documentation: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4545/how-do-you-discover-what-permissions-an-ad-group-has-if-you-have-no-documentati